Harvard refernces without URL and ISSN if DOI is given
I'm correcting the referencing in my thesis. It is required to use harvard referencing, looking like this:

Freeman, R., McMahon, C. & Godfrey, P. (2017). An exploration of the potential for re-
distributed manufacturing to contribute to a sustainable, resilient city. International Jour-
nal of Sustainable Engineering 10(4-5), pp. 260–271. DOI: 10 . 1080 / 19397038 . 2017 . 1318969.

and

ISO 9004 (2000). Quality magement systems – Guidelines for performance improvements.
Standard. Geneve, Switzerland: International Organization for Standardization.

Using the code for referencing in the template in combination with a linked .bib from Zotero, I'm facing the issue that URL, DOI and ISSN (and some other not needed info) are displayed. Looking like this:

Ali, W. A., Roccotelli, M. & Fanti, M. P. (May 17, 2022). Digital Twin in Intelligent Trans-
portation Systems: a Review. In: 2022 8th International Conference on Control, Deci-
sion and Information Technologies (CoDIT). 2022 8th International Conference on Con-
trol, Decision and Information Technologies (CoDIT). Istanbul, Turkey: IEEE, pp. 576–581. ISBN: 978-1-66549-607-0. DOI: 10.1109/CoDIT55151.2022.9804017. URL: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9804017/ (visited on 06/06/2024).

Is there a way to define the code to only show the required format or export a .bib only including the info to be displayed?
The code looks like this:
% setting up proper formats for the reference list and citation styles
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{citetitle}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1\isdot} 

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}

I would be very thankful for any tip or solution.
Thanks :))

Welcome to TeX.SE. I've taken the liberty of pretty-printing your code, deleting the 'cross-referencing' tag, and adding the 'biblatex' tag. Feel free to revert.

So, for the URL, let's change the doi+eprint+url macro. We need to check if the DOI is there. If not, we can show the URL.
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
    \newunit%
    \ifbool{not test {\iffieldundef{doi}}}%
        {\iftoggle{bbx:doi}%
            {\printfield{doi}%
            \newunit}%
            {}}%
        {\iftoggle{bbx:eprint}%
            {\usebibmacro{eprint}%
            \newunit}%
            {}%
        \iftoggle{bbx:url}%
            {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
            \newunit}%
            {}}}

For the ISSN field, try this command. It will hide the ISSN field if there the DOI.
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \ifentrytype{article}%
        {\iffieldundef{doi}%
            {}%
            {\clearfield{issn}}}%
        {}}

It should work, in relation to your question.
